# keep a js timer counting

Tags: javascript, html

i have a small issue with my timer I'm trying to make a timer with a specific time 
but the problem is if I refresh the page he start again
there is anyway to keep the timer counting even I refresh the page 
and loop this time ??

```js
  var temps = 86400;
var seconds = temps;
function timer() {
  var days        = Math.floor(seconds/24/60/60);
  var hoursLeft   = Math.floor((seconds) - (days*86400));
  var hours       = Math.floor(hoursLeft/3600);
  var minutesLeft = Math.floor((hoursLeft) - (hours*3600));
  var minutes     = Math.floor(minutesLeft/60);
  var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
  function pad(n) {
    return (n < 10 ? "0" + n : n);
  }
  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = pad(days) + ":" + pad(hours) + ":" + pad(minutes) + ":" + pad(remainingSeconds);
  if (seconds == 0) {
    clearInterval(countdownTimer);
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Completed";
  } else {
    seconds--;
  }
}
var countdownTimer = setInterval('timer()', 1000);
```

```html
<span id="countdown" class="countdown gauge__countdown"> </span>
```

Comment: If you are doing it without API call you should set the element in the localstorage so even if you refresh the page you will have the count in your storage.

Comment: but I want to keep it counting not storing the last value

Comment: I deleted my answer, but this can be done if anyone is wants to answer. Well at least in can be faked. If you save an end date in local storage (which is the current date plus OP's 86400 seconds) then just create a timer that checks to see if the current date/time is equal to the end date/time. Since it is based on the browser's time, when the browser is refreshed, it will have the illusion that the timer has been continuing.

Comment: thanks but how can I do it I don't know a lot about locale storage !!

Comment: I dont understand the use case here. Is it something just to try out or part of some real time case? I don't think its a part of some real time use case, with Local storage you can play with one browser, but what if you open it on other browser? Best solution is to make an API call while loading the page, get the time left and show the countdown time on that!

Comment: I need the easiest solution to keep the timer counting no need to create an api just for a timer !